# Cylindrical coordinates with ellipsoids?

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

First, is the question incorrect in describing S as a paraboloid, not an ellipsoid? And second, how exactly do we apply the triple integral with cylindrical coordinates? Moreover, how can we use cylindrical coordinates with r not being the same as that of a cylinder (as in the r keeps changing as we're travelling in the z-direction)? Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Note that the surface is called an ellipsoid later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$, we can determine the range for $z$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$.  In particular, we let $\theta$ range between $0$ and $2\pi$.  Once we know $\theta$ we can determine a range of values for $r$.  The projection of our region to the $xy$-plane is the solid ellipse
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}\leq1.
\end{equation}
Perhaps you can convince yourself that the point on the boundary of this ellipse in the $\theta$-direction is $(2\cos\theta,3\sin\theta)$.  So the upper bound for $r$ in this direction is
\begin{equation}
r(\theta) = \sqrt{4\cos^2\theta+9\sin^2\theta} = \sqrt{4+5\sin^2\theta}.
\end{equation}
So the ellipse in the $xy$-plane is given by
\begin{equation}
\{(r,\theta):0\leq\theta\leq 2\pi,0\leq r\leq\sqrt{4+5\sin^2\theta}\}.
\end{equation}
Finally, where can $z$ live?  Well, if we know $r$ and $\theta$ we can write
\begin{equation}
\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}+z^2\leq 1
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta}{4}+\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta}{9}+z^2\leq 1,
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
-\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta}{4}-\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta}{9}}\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-\frac{r^2\cos^2\theta}{4}-\frac{r^2\sin^2\theta}{9}}.
\end{equation}
In a triple integral that has $z$ as the innermost integral, these would be the bounds of that integral. The bounds for the $r$- and $\theta$-integrals can be taken from the above expression for the ellipse.

This isn't necessarily the *only* way to describe our ellipsoid in cylindrical coordinates (perhaps you want $r$ to be the innermost integral instead of $z$), but hopefully it addresses your question about the relationship between the bounds of $r$ and $z$.

Comment: That does answer my question, thank you!
There's one though process I'm having trouble with: does the fact that the boundaries of z are in terms of theta and r prevent the triple integral from interpreting the boundaries of r as that describing a circle?

Comment: The setup above uses $r$ and $\theta$ to describe an ellipse in the plane, and then looks at the range of $z$ values above and below each point in that ellipse.  To do what you suggest you can fix a $z$ value and write your equation as $x^2/4+y^2/9=1-z^2$.  This is an ellipse (since $z$ is fixed), so you can find bounds for $r$ in terms of $\theta$ and $z$.  Notice that the $z$-slices of our region are ellipses, not circles.